# Email block list question

Tags: database-design, blocking

I am validating email block list for 3 things:
1) Block email like: abc@test.com
2) Domain like: test.com
3) SubDomain like: .com

So when a user submits an email, it can be rejected from a block list for any of the 3 reasons. The question is do i need 3 separate tables for this and how will it work? System takes the email runs it in block list 1, then list 2 then list 3 or is there some way t write a function or something that can do all 3 runs at once?

And is this best stored in a RDMS or NoSQL implementation? The domain and email block lists around approx 500,000 entries. Email lists will grow longer as i add spam emails to the list. Sumdomain list will be around 10-15 depending on some custom logic.

Note: This list will even be used for email filters on site to reject mail as spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex, or the basic LIKE syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_banned WHERE ban_pattern LIKE 'someone@domain.ext'
```

And while banning use either:

```
abc@test.com
*@test.com
*.com
```

In MySQL the * is %.

**EDIT**

I missed the second part of the question out sorry. Imho, storing this in the RDBMS impl. is far enough, I don't see no problem.

Comment: So i need 3 queues then as i need all 3 cases?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to have 3 queues or store everything in one single table. I'd use one unique queue and in case you want to know what type of ban it is, you can also use a field for the type: Email, Email Domain or Domain.